# Convert row values into columns based on row values multi level hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a ORACLE table like this

```
---------------------------------------
DATE        |  USERID | DOMAIN | VALUE
---------------------------------------
03/16/2016     1001     ASIA      10
03/16/2016     1001     EUROPE    20
03/16/2016     1002     ASIA      20
03/17/2016     1001     ASIA      20
03/17/2016     1002     EUROPE    10
----------------------------------------
```

I want to translate this table to a view something like this

```
 -------------------------------------
 DATE       |  USERID | ASIA | EUROPE  
 -------------------------------------
 03/16/2016     1001     10     20
 03/16/2016     1002     20      
 03/17/2016     1001     20
 03/17/2016     1002            10 
 -------------------------------------
```

If I tried to use PIVOT I can do it on a user level, but don't know how to get the date, user level. Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIVOT seems to achieve the result you need:

```
SQL> with test (DATE_, USERID, DOMAIN, VALUE)
  2  as (
  3   select '03/16/2016',     1001     ,'ASIA'      ,10 from dual union all
  4   select '03/16/2016',     1001     ,'EUROPE'    ,20 from dual union all
  5   select '03/16/2016',     1002     ,'ASIA'      ,20 from dual union all
  6   select '03/17/2016',     1001     ,'ASIA'      ,20 from dual union all
  7   select '03/17/2016',     1002     ,'EUROPE'    ,10 from dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT *
 10  FROM   (select *
 11          from test)
 12  PIVOT ( sum(value) FOR (domain) IN ('ASIA', 'EUROPE'))
 13  ORDER BY 1, 2;

DATE_          USERID     'ASIA'   'EUROPE'
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
03/16/2016       1001         10         20
03/16/2016       1002         20
03/17/2016       1001         20
03/17/2016       1002                    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `case` expression to chose Asia or Europe:

```
select DATE, USERID,
       sum(case when DOMAIN = 'ASIA' then VALUE end) as asia
       sum(case when DOMAIN = 'EUROPE' then VALUE end) as europe
from tablename
group by DATE, USERID
```

Answer for products not supporting modern Oracle versions' `PIVOT`.

Comment: Oracle 11.2 allows PIVOT on multiple columns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988799/477563

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT function with

```
pivot 
(
   count(VALUE)
   for DOMAIN in ("ASIA", "EUROPE")
)
```

, wrap the query in a subselect and then group the result by UserID.