# Query to make each rows into single row

Tags: sql, oracle

**Problem**: I have to make each row as column using SQL statement.

**Source Table**

```
Colour_id   Colour_desc Value1_min  Value1_max  Value2_min  Value2_max
1           Green          0          0.499        0        0.299
2           Amber          0.5        0.8         0.03      0.05
```

**I want a output looks like below:**

```
Value1_min_Green    Value1_max_Green    Value2_min_Green    Value2_max_Green    Value1_min_Amber    Value1_max_Green    Value2_min_Amber    Value2_max_Green
0                     0.499               0                 0.299          0.5                       0.8                0.03                           0.05
```

Any Approach or suggestion to get above result as output?

Comment: Duplicate of [Pivoting of data using two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987067/pivoting-of-data-using-two-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the 2 rows value in 1 row output (`source` is table name):

```
select green.Value1_min as Value1_min_Green green.Value1_max as Value1_max_Green,
       green.Value2_min as Value2_min_Green green.Value2_max as Value2_max_Green,
       amber.Value1_min as Value1_min_Amber amber.Value1_max as Value1_max_Amber,
       amber.Value2_min as Value2_min_Amber amber.Value2_max as Value2_max_Amber
  from source as green, source as amber
 where amber.Colour_desc = 'Amber'
   and green.Colour_desc = 'Green'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when colour_desc = 'green' then value1_min end) as value1_min_green,
       max(case when colour_desc = 'green' then value2_min end) as value2_min_green,
       max(case when colour_desc = 'amber' then value1_min end) as value1_min_amber,
       max(case when colour_desc = 'amber' then value2_min end) as value2_min_amber
from t;
```

Adding additional colors is quite easy -- and really incurs no additional performance overhead because the query is already doing an aggregation.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but it's not working for my scenario. since i want to restrict the output data to only 1 rows. but while running your approach, i am getting all the 3 rows.

Comment: @Ganesh : You should use `MAX (` for all the case expressions